# Passing a class method return value to a class variable within constructor

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I am attempting to initialise a variable within a Javascript Class by passing it a return value from a class method, like this:

```
class Agent{
    constructor(batteryCapacity){
        this.currentDate = this.getDate();
        this.ethereumAddress = this.getAccount();
        this.balance = this.getAgentBalance();
    }


    getDate(){
        day = currentDate.getDate();
        month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
        year = currentDate.getFullYear();
        //this.currentDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        //Can I assign the variable within this method?
        return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    }

    async getAccount(index) {
        accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        return accounts[index];
    }

    async getAgentBalance() {
        this.balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(ethereumAddress);
        return balance;
    }
```

I get the error: currentDate is not defined. However, I feel like what I am doing is literally defining it with the return value from getDate(), so why am I getting this error?
Alternatively, would i be able to assign variables to the class within the method  functions and simply call the function, this.getDate() and assign this.currentDate within it like i describe in the commented section of that function?

Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: It's `currentDate` *in* `getDate()` method that is not defined. If I get it right, your `getDate()` is actually `getCurrentDate()` and should be `static`

Comment: use `this.currentDate`

Comment: It's `currentDate.getDate();` that complains, not the `.currentDate` property of your instance

Comment: Thank you haim770, i missed that detail and now it works, however if i use static before getDate() function definition, i get this.getDate() is not a function. Why do you think it needs to be static?